# Self-updating graphs over time with Python and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm not familiar with matplotlib in Python. What I want to achieve is to plot data over time using a text file which receives new data every certain period.

The text file format is the following:

data,time

1,2015-07-05 11:20:00

What I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
import dateutil

pullData = open('sampleText.txt', 'r').read()
dataArray = pullData.split('\n')

datestrings = []
plt_data = []

for eachLine in dataArray:
    if len(eachLine)>1:
        y,x = eachLine.split(',')
        plt_data.append(int(y))
        datestrings.append(x)

dates = [dateutil.parser.parse(s) for s in datestrings]

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
plt.xticks( rotation=25 )

ax=plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks(dates)

xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%m-%d %H:%M')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
plt.plot(dates,plt_data, "o-")
plt.show()
```

This is pretty much what I could get through different tutorials/previous questions.

As you may see, this code works for plotting data over time, but I don't understand how can I adapt it in a way that the graph would update itself with new data.

Comment: @tom10 You're right, I've just edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: It's clear now. Thanks. I deleted my original comment because I think you were using "real-time" in the commonly understood way in the first place so now my original comment is just confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your text file is being written to, and appended with new data.

You can then use inotify to get alerts when the file is modified and 'hang' a function to that event to update your graph.

Have a look at [this page](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki/List-of-Examples), where there are several examples on how to use pyinotify to capture events. A [`minimal example`](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/blob/master/python2/examples/loop.py) is also provided, which shows the 'structure' of your program:

```
import pyinotify

# Instantiate a new WatchManager (will be used to store watches).
wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()

# Associate this WatchManager with a Notifier (will be used to report and
# process events).
notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm)

# Add a new watch on /tmp for ALL_EVENTS.
wm.add_watch('/tmp', pyinotify.ALL_EVENTS)

# Loop forever and handle events.
notifier.loop()
```

Most importantly, the pyinotify.ALL_EVENTS can be changed to listen
only to events you're interested in (such as file modifications, or
creation if the file does not exist yet)

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it with a [function animation](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/examples/animation/basic_example.html) or you can use this code:

```
line, = ax.plot(dates,plt_data, "o-")
plt.show(block=False)

while True:
  # use some method as the one proposed by jcoppens to read your new data
  line.set_data(new_dates, new_data)
  # timeout/sleep until new data arrives
```

Comment: I've tried what you said using as a notifier `os.stat('sampleText.txt').st_mtime` . But what happens is that the figure window automatically hangs.